# SignalR subscribe to event with param

Tags: signalr

I need to subscribe to server events from client, so syntax is

```
Hub.client.[my event here]= function
```

It's working, but what if I need to subscribe with params, i.e. user need to see only unread messages or a list of messages with a criteria. So I want the same event subscription with modifiers. Like :

```
Hub.subscribe.messages({read:true}) = function ....
```

At server side I want to push updates only for clients that subscribed to this type of criteria and specific parameters. 
I know I can make groups of clients but that seems to be overhead and not best practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used the client syntax:

```
Hub.client["MethodName_" + dynamicParam] = function
```

And server side syntax:

```
HubContext.Clients.All.Invoke(string.Format("MethodName_{0}", dynamicParam), data);
```

That way I can register to dynamic events based on the client selection of "dynamicParam"